# "swept in this extraordinary, incredible fashion into > invisibility— into some other place." understanding the meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

Reading an old story, I have some problems with understanding the following (esp. the part in bold):

> it was this very day fifty years ago—February 13—the man disappeared
> from its shadows; **swept in this extraordinary, incredible fashion into
> invisibility— into some other place.**

My understanding (using simpler words where I am more certain about the meaning):
...abruptly carried away, in a very extraordinary and incredible fashion, so that he became invisible and got into another place.

Is that correct? I have particular problems with understanding of "into invisibility".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you understand it correctly. "[he was] swept into invisibility..." means he became invisible. The author uses "swept into", which distributes to the two conditions in apposition: invisibility = some other [unknown] place.